# Can I Use my Keyboard and mouse from one laptop, and use it on another

Tags: laptop, keyboard, mouse

I have 2 laptops. Laptop 1 (As ill call it) has water damage, so i cannot use the mouse or keyboard. Laptop 2 is working fine. I was wondering if I can use the keyboard and mouse from laptop 2 and use it on laptop 1. Laptop 1 is more powerful so thats why i would like to use it instead.

Comment: By "keyboard and mouse" do you actually mean "built-in keyboard and pointing device"?

Answer (score 0):

You may talking about the keboard and mouse pad built in the laptop body.

Yes, it the hardware interface is the same. When you open your Laptop 1, you will see connection port from keyboard to the mother board. If the connection cable is the same with Laptop 2, you just simply exchange it.

I replaced my laptop keyboard before. I purchased the keyboard in ebay at that time.